# Call interface method on F# object from C#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

Given an F# type:

```
type Foo() =
    member this.Prop with get() = ()

    interface IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose() = ()
```

In C#, I create the object, but I can't call `Dispose()`:

```cs
var x = new Foo();
x.Dispose(); // compile error, x does not contain a definition of Dispose
```

However, I can write:

```cs
((IDisposable)x).Dispose(); // works, but I don't like the cast
```

Is there any way to avoid the cast in C#? Is this related to the way F# doesn't automatically let you call `.Dispose()` on the `Foo` type from within F#?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Interface implementations in F# are explicit by default.  Hence the methods are not visible unless seen from the type converted to the interface (some form of casting).

To work around this expose an instance method which has the same signature as the interface version.  Then have the interface on forward to the instance function.  For example

```
type Foo() =
    member this.Prop with get() = ()
    member this.Dispose() = ()

    interface IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose() = this.Dispose()
```

Comment: One more reason for me (and everybody else) not to do OOP in F# :)

Comment: I dont think thats a reason not to use OOP in F#.  Using OOP in F# should be a design decision based on complexity of the project and the overall design.

Comment: Is there any rationale behind this decision, or was it because of backwards compatibilty to OCaml? In my mind, when a Student 'is a' Person, I would assume the Student has an age I can just ask for without having to cast to IPerson first. Do you know why this was implemented like this?

Answer (score 3):

How about, for this particular interface:

```
using (var x = new Foo()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Usually I would, but in this particular case I have List<Foo>, so have to do finally {foreach (var x in foos){x.Dispose();}